# Database design for student course and fee payment

Tags: ms-access

I am currently designing a database for storing student records, and the course which they will attend. According to my design one student can take multiple course but, I am facing a problem because I can't figure out how to create a fee table so that student fees can be stored.

A student should be able to pay the fee for multiple courses which he has taken.

If a student has taken two courses, he/she can pay the fee for that course separately, so we can make a report on how much he/she has paid for a given course.

The link to my database design [is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxa01Ur3XWvNbFVfSkdVVzNISzQ/view?usp=sharing).

Please help me create the fee table, and please check whether my design is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `fee table` because you know the following already:

- student_id
- course_id
- price associated with course_id
- discount associated with student X course

All you have to do is make a query where you list these 4 information and you can filter it by student_id to get an individual student fees.

Comment: Here fee means the amount given by student per month out of his total course fee

Comment: Yes, your "fee" should be added up prices of the courses a given student is taking (with associated discount accounted for). You still do not need a new table for this.

Comment: Hi,I have to design an database for fee management of students. Each class have different fee and that varies in almost every year. I need to get student fees report in day,month and year wise.Fee report contains paid and to be paid. If fee of class changes the to be paid is there if the student already paid full. Can you please help me with this??